# xml parsing in this way but in MainViewModel

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

i'm working on an app which uses xml parsing to fetch the datas. after few searching on the internet, finally i found the code that suits my need. as a note, i placed it at MainPage.xaml.cs

```
        try
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }

            XElement profiler = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

            listBox2.ItemsSource = from developers in profiler.Descendants("status")
                                   select new ItemViewModel
                                   {
                                       Tweet = developers.Element("text").Value,
                                       TweetImage = developers.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                                       TweetSender = developers.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value,
                                   };
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + "\nThis may caused by your IP has made over 150 request in less than 1 hour. Try checking back in the next hour or try restarting your phone.");
            return;
        }
```

but, when it goes to details page, it truned into an exception. i want that code placed in MainViewModel class in the WebClient download completion eventhandler. what line should i edit in order to make xml parsing in this way, but in MainViewModel. Any answer will be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this in your MainViewModel, First You need to create a model class that contains Teet,TweetImage etc.. Then you need to place you parsed result into a "List/ Observable" Collection and then bind that collection in to your listbox through xaml. This will resolve your issue.

Comment: what should i change on this line: 
 listBox2.ItemsSource = from developers in profiler.Descendants("status")

Comment: instead of listBox2.ItemsSource you need to give List<YourClassName> ParsedList.. and the Bind this parsed list to ur UI